# What should I do with e-mail scammers?

Tags: email, scam

I have the IP address of a scammer (I convinced them to hit my web server) whose mail made it through my filters and would like to do something meaningful about it.  Can I?  I thought about telling their ISP, but `dig -x` shows the netblock owner as a giant telecoms company.   Have any of you had success in the past with bringing some form of justice to these bottom feeders?

Comment: "convinced them to hit my web server" - sounds like you're asking for trouble...

Comment: @Ben: Just mail with embedded img tags...Curiosity is a powerful thing.

Comment: If you go out fishing for such things you can hardly complain when you catch one.

Comment: @John: They sent me scammy mail (that made it through the filters) first.  I just replied.  I'm not complaining about having caught one; I just want to know what to do with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the dig report has an abuse address, send a detailed account of what happened to it. Send the IP address, dates & times, what the scammer sent you, and any reasonable information. Leave your opinion out, stick to the facts. Don't expect a response, except the usual automated one.

Past that, not much. Black-hole that IP and hope they stay away. Many ISPs do take reports of abuse very seriously.

Comment: I was hoping for some secret international law enforcement agency known only to sysadmins, but this will have to do.

Comment: Closest thing to that is [Spamhaus](http://spamhaus.org). My first round of filtering is just checking their zen and drop DBs, that catches 99% with minimal server load.

Comment: @NMichaels - there is no cabal.

Comment: If ISPs have clients mass spamming and they don't respond to places like Spamhaus, they may find their IP netblocks in these RBL systems for mail servers to block. abuseat.org is a good RBL as well.

Answer (score 1):

Like ChrisS said, you should definitely forward the message to the ISP.  In addition, since phishing/spamming/whathaveyou is technically illegal, you can also file a complaint with the [Internet Crime Complaint Center](http://www.ic3.gov/default.aspx). I would not expect your single complaint to be acted upon. However, it files the information so it can be used as part of a larger investigation should one occur.